# python plotting moving average python error

Tags: python-2.7

i made some code where i need to make a plot where my data is persed to moving average

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Open Data/File
data = open('iphonevsandroid.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter=',')

#Define lists
iphone_data = []
android_data = []
dateTime = []
stringdates = []
#iphone_data_average = []
#android_data_average = []


for row in reader:

    first_date_row = row[0]
    first_date = row[0][:-13]

    if row[1] != 'iphone':
        iphone_data.append(int(row[1]))

    if row[2] != 'android':
        android_data.append(int(row[2]))

    if row[0] != 'week':
        stringdates.append(row[0][:-13])

for item in stringdates:

    dateTime.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(item, '%Y-%m-%d'))        

def movingaverage(values,window):
    weigths = np.repeat(1.0, window)/window
    #including valid will REQUIRE there to be enough datapoints.
    #for example, if you take out valid, it will start @ point one,
    #not having any prior points, so itll be 1+0+0 = 1 /3 = .3333
    smas = np.convolve(values, weigths, 'valid')
    return smas # as a numpy array

movingaverage(iphone_data,3)
movingaverage(android_data,3)

plt.ylabel('Indsæt y label')
plt.xlabel('Indsæt x label')

plt.plot(dateTime,movingaverage(iphone_data,3)+2)
plt.plot(dateTime,movingaverage(android_data,3)+2)
plt.show()
```

My problem is that i get this error: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension.

I know its because of the len of the values,

if i print the len of:

```
print len(dateTime)
print len(movingaverage(iphone_data,3))
print len(movingaverage(android_data,3))
```

i get: 
528
526
526
How do i get dateTime to 526???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
smas = np.convolve(values, weigths, 'valid')
```

should be

```
smas = np.convolve(values, weigths, 'same')
```

and if you don't want the border values, then you will have to remove them yourself, that is for odd window lengths:

```
smas = np.convolve(values, weigths, 'valid')[(window-1)/2:-(window-1)/2]
```

Note that you would also have to remove these values from `android_data` and `iphone_data`.